# Plugin with id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' not found in new version android

Tags: android, gradle, android-architecture-navigation

I'm going to https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation but I get an error when syncing the id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' plugin which you can see in the image below

[image build.gradle(moduleApp)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUt3p.png)

[image builde.gradle(project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GotM.png)

[image My dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9sT1.png)

[image My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auAQV.png)

Comment: Have you tried just swapping the order and declaring the `id 'com.android.application'` plugin first?

Comment: No, I added the dependencies section libraries first, then the build script, and finally the plugin. @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this error, add the following code to build.gradle (project) and sync the project

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.1") 
    }
}
```

Next add this code to build.gradle(module)

```
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
```

Comment: Thank you, it was a good answer